# Dual boot Win7 + Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I bought a new win10 lappy and have already started hating it. I want to go back to Ubuntu but some of my office tasks require me to have Windows, so I guess the only solution is to have my lappy dual booted.

I don't want windows10, So i am going to install win 7 and then dual boot it with Ubuntu.

I've never done this before so I need detailed guidance. Do I need to back up all my drives or just the C drive before installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need any of your data, you can format all the disk.
Then boot win7 using  bootable pendrive.
When your win7 installation is complete, then you can take the iso file of ubuntu in pen drive and make the separate drive of approx 10GB.
Then boot ubuntu using pendrive.